# Fields in redux form returns a value of undefined

Tags: redux, redux-form

i've implememt a submission form using redux-form:

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
const Filters = ( {fields: {symbol, side, status}} ) => {
    console.log(side);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'FiltersAccounts',  // a unique identifier for this form
  fields: ['symbol', 'side', 'status']
})(Filters);
```

Why the console.log shows me undefined? Am i missing something??

Comment: Was this fixed? Will be interested to know the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code misses closing bracket in `Filters` function.

```
const Filters = ( {fields: {symbol, side, status}} ) => {
    console.log(side);
} // <- this was missing
```

## Answer update

`reduxForm` doesn't accept `fields` config option and passes down only `props` listed on [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/)

Comment: This code is the part i call these props. I close my brackets properly. This is not the error but thanks for your response.